# How does the following code works printf("%c")?

Tags: c, if-statement, output, printf

I wanted to know how the following program is working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    while(1){
        if(printf("%d",printf("%c")))
        break;
        else
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I did not know how the part printf("%c") is working and therefore the whole program.I am aware of writing something like printf("%c", 'a'); like that but how is it working without providing the character to be printed? My question is what does the following program prints and how does it prints so?

I have tried to run the program, sometimes it prints nothing, but sometimes it is printing some random character followed by 1. I am not able to get how it is working, can someone please explain what is going behind the code and how it is printing that random characters, and why there is one at the end?

Here are some output I am getting

[image: Output]

[image: Output]

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour: it only _appears_ to work, but it's broken.

Comment: The inner `printf` call is missing an argument:  `printf("%c")`  The `%c` format requires an integer argument, which is printed as a character.  For example, `printf("%c", 'x')` would be valid.  Your compiler should have given you a warning about it (if not, look into increasing the warning level).

Comment: Save time - enable more warnings to quickly detect  `printf("%c")` is problem code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cool *wrong* program you have.

`printf("%c")` attempts to print a single character that is supposed to be the second parameter. However, since you have never passed the second parameter, the function prints whatever is *in the register that was supposed to have* the second parameter. In other words, some random character. However, it prints one character and returns 1: the number of characters printed.

That 1 is in turn printed by `printf("%d",printf("%c"))`. Now you have a random character followed by 1, and since the outer `printf` also prints one character, it returns 1.

Finally, `if(printf("%d",printf("%c")))` interprets that later 1 as true and breaks the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to *Undefined Behavior*. You fail to have sufficient number of arguments for the format  you specify, e.g.

[C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p2)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p2) "*If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.*" [7.21.6.1(p9)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) "*If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*"

Answer (score 0):

This is about format bugs.

Look at this code, when execute printf("%d", 123), the program will push number 123 onto the stack, and then push string "%d", when printf meets "%d", it will read the value on the top of the stack, so printf find the number 123.

Now look at this code, printf("%c"), program will push string "%c" onto the stack, and try to read value on the top of the stack, you haven't push a value for printf, so printf will still find value, but the value is random, so you might get a random value.